# How to read and update secrets information in parameters.json file of Azure Logic App from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have Azure Logic App that processes messages from Service Bus session-based queue using When one or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock) connector and then inserting into SQL Database.

**Note: In Azure Logic App, this is When one or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock) first trigger.**

I want to protect the connection strings of Azure Service Bus and Azure SQL Database. For that I used Azure Key Vault to store connection strings information of Azure Service Bus and Azure SQL Database.

I have followed this [documentation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-better-protect-your-secrets-in-logic-apps-using-key-vault-connector/) to read secrets from Azure Key Vault.

But I want to use the secrets information in **parameters.json** file. Because currently I have hardcoded the connection strings of Azure Service Bus and Azure SQL Database in **parameters.json** file.

So, can anyone suggest me ead and update secrets information in **parameters.json** file of Azure Logic App from Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Resource Manager Templates allow for integration of parameters with KeyVault to pull secrets from it.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556)

Which should look like this

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "adminLogin": {
        "value": "exampleadmin"
      },
      "adminPassword": {
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
          },
          "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
        }
      },
      "sqlServerName": {
        "value": "<your-server-name>"
      }
  }
}
```

Remember to add Logic Apps secret obfuscation

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#secure-data-in-run-history-by-using-obfuscation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#secure-data-in-run-history-by-using-obfuscation?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556)